# Android Studio SDK installation issue after update

Tags: android, android-studio

I bought a course at Udemy, but the version that the instructor uses is older than mine. Thus, I couldn't finish my installation successfully. In the version that he used, there were 3 boxes to check on the first opening. Android Studio, SDK, and virtual device. He checked all of them. But mine doesn't have SDK box at all.

I am totally new to the Android studio and using windows 10. How should I install the sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Android Studio, and if you want to configure SDK settings or whatever that is related to SDK, go to **Tools -> SDK Manager**

If you want to configure virtual devices go to **Tools -> AVD Manager**.

Answer (score 0):

see the Android Studio [intro](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update), which explains how to use the SDK manager.

it's toolbar icon had been changed recently, which may lead to confusion.

use `x86` emulator images for best performance, when `HAXM` is supported.